# Why does the wrong object get tested in this RSpec setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, activerecord, rspec

I'm having trouble with an RSpec test, and I suspect it may be to do with my explicit use of subject in the before block. Notably, I am testing ActiveRecord objects that have a has_many / belongs_to relationship. This is my failing test, in which I'm trying to assert that the parent has some behaviour based on the event of adding the child:

```
subject { FactoryGirl.create(:parent) }
let(:child) { FactoryGirl.build(:child) }

context "with added child object" do
  before { subject.children << child }
  its(:foo) { is.expected_to eq("bar")
end
```

In my parent model I have some simple logic based on adding the child record which works outside of the test. Since it doesn't work in the test, I switched to writing the spec part out long-form to try and understand why:

```
before do
  puts "subject is #{subject}"
  puts "child is #{child}"
  subject.children << child 
  puts "#{child} is now attached to #{child.parent}"
end

it "has the correct response" do
  puts "testing against subject #{subject}"
  expect(subject.foo).to eq("bar")
end
```

And the output I got suggests that something weird is happening - that the subject I attach the child to is a *different one to the one in the setup and testing blocks*:

```
subject is #<Parent:0x00561eddf1a7a0>                                                  
child is #<Child:0x00561edcdd7fb0>
#<Child:0x00561edcdd7fb0> is now attached to #<Parent:0x00561edd11c040>
testing against subject #<Parent:0x00561eddf1a7a0>
```

Am I doing something wrong with subject to cause this behaviour? Is there a better way to write this test?

## Update based on suggestion below

When I structure the test like this, it passes, and the output doesn't include any mystery second version of the parent.

```
before do
  child = FactoryGirl.create(:child, parent: parent)      
end

it "has the correct response" do
  # some puts to check the states of the various models here
  expect(subject.foo).to eq("bar")
end
```

However, this isn't how clients are using the class - it's possible to add children through a number of different methods, and I'd like the model to behave in the same way regardless.

This also doesn't answer the question - **where is the extra object coming from in the first setup?**

Comment: I don't get what you're actually testing?  The foo method does something with the children?  Adding the child to the parent doesn't make it the subject.  The subject will still be the parent, what happens is what I would expect to happen.

Comment: @dexx I'm testing the behaviour of one of the parent's methods, based on the events that are fired when the child is added. I want the subject to still be the parent.

Why do you expect there to be a second parent object created in the test that the child gets attached to? Or maybe I wasn't clear enough about highlighting that in the question.

Comment: I see the issue now, I was looking at the subject is and testing against subject puts.  What is in the factory for the child? Is `child_to_attach` a typo? or another let/method?

Comment: @j-dexx excuse me, that was indeed a typo. The child factory is pretty straightforward, just sets a few required fields.

Comment: is one of those the parent object?

Comment: That was one of my thoughts as well, unfortunately not. Just a title and another bit of text.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it like this:

```
let(:parent) { FactoryGirl.create(:parent) }
let(:child) { FactoryGirl.build(:child) }
subject { parent }

context "with added child object" do
  before { parent.children << child }
  its(:foo) { is.expected_to eq("bar")
end
```

Or if child object has a relation with parent then:

```
let!(:parent) { FactoryGirl.create(:parent) }
let!(:child) { FactoryGirl.build(:child, parent: parent) }
subject { parent }

context "with added child object" do
  its(:foo) { is.expected_to eq("bar")
end
```

Let me know the result.

Comment: For the first example, where we assign using the bucket operator, I end up with the same behaviour as before: the test fails, and the child ends up with a completely different parent (I don't understand why).

Comment: For the second example, it's the same - unless I `create` instead of `build` the child, in which case the test passes (!) and the child ends up correctly attached. It seems something is going wrong with that bucket assignment, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: May be you need to do `parent.save!` after `parent.children << child`

Comment: If you have a relation between parent and child classes, i believe 2nd approach is better for that case. Replacing `build` with `create`.

Comment: Did you add option `autosave: true` when defining your association? See this link: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html

Comment: The problem is that "create" doesn't reflect how a client would actually use the class - people will add on child objects in a number of ways. I'm doing some further explanation in the question now, including looking into what you've suggested.